# Using Maple to find the normal vector

Tags: maple

I'm trying to find the normal vector to the level surface $xyz = 1$ at an arbitrary point $(a, b, c)$

```
with(Student[VectorCalculus]);
PrincipalNormal(PositionVector([x, y, 1/(x*y), x, y]));
```

Any idea what's wrong with my code? I keep getting "could not determine unique indeterminate: {x, y}
"

I tried to read the documentation but the functions were given in parametric form.

Comment: at which point?

Comment: You need one parenthesis , i.e. PrincipalNormal(PositionVector([x, y, 1/(xy), x, y])$\mathbf{\bigg)}$;. When you get that error it is because of incomplete parenthesis, or something similar.

Comment: @imranfat in terms of a, b and c

Comment: @Jack No worries.

Comment: See https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/132980-Surface-Normal-In-Vector-Calculus.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace **xy** with **x*y**. Juxtaposition does not imply multiplication; rather, **xy** is treated as a distinct variable.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed at least part of the problem. Now I'm getting "could not determine unique indeterminate: {x, y}"

Comment: As far as I can tell from the documentation, the command **PricipalNormal** is for curves, not surfaces.